# Can two dual GPU ATI video cards run together in Crossfire?

Tags: graphics-card, crossfire

Can I run two ATI Radeon HD 3870 X2 graphics cards together in Crossfire, or will this not work due to the dual GPUs (X2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Crossfire. See [here](http://www.tbreak.com/reviews/article.php?id=589):

> A little over three weeks back, AMD
>   unleashed their HD3870 X2 graphics
>   card which put AMD back on top for the
>   fastest graphics card. Although the
>   card featured a Crossfire connector
>   bridge, drivers were not available to
>   take advantage of this feature. AMD
>   has now released their 8.3 Catalyst
>   drivers that allow you to run two
>   HD3870 X2 graphics cards in Crossfire
>   mode allowing you to harness the power
>   of four GPUs.

Comment: oh okay thank you very much. :) (Found only irrevelant hits through google... my google-fu is still on a low level. :))

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, all dual-GPU ATI cards can be run in a Crossfire config for four effective GPUs. The maximum number of GPUs in crossfire is four.

There are not a lot of dual-GPU cards to choose from though, and the ones out there are expensive.

(it is also possible and supported to use three or four single GPU cards on one motherboard, if you can find a mobo that has the right number of video card capable PCI express slots!)

Any four-GPU config would also require a truly massive power supply and extremely good cooling, so be careful. This is the one instance where all those ridiculously over-specced gamer rigs are actually justified!

Comment: I saw your recent tweet. ^^" Did that happen only in the BF3 Beta, or generally everywhere?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the BF3 beta